# About Mostowski's Collapse, how can you explain the starting set not being transitive?

Tags: set-theory

The Theorem as it has been presented to me states as follows:

Let $r$ be a relation on a set $M$ that is well founded and extensional (satisfies then axioms of foundation and extension), then there exists a transitive set N and a bijection called Mostowski's Collapse $\pi:M\rightarrow N$ such that $\pi$ is an isomorphism, i.e.
$(\forall x,y \in M) (x\ r\ y \leftrightarrow \pi(x)\in \pi(y))$. Moreover N and $\pi$ are unique.

My question would be, let $x\ r\ y$ where $y\ r\ z$, because $\pi$ is an isomorphism $\pi(x)\in \pi(y)$ and $\pi(y)\in \pi(z)$, and because $N$ is transitive $\pi(x)\in\pi(z)$ meaning $x r z$. So the relation $r$ is transitive.

Now the above makes absolutely no sense. I've seen Mostowski Collapse formulated for structures in the language of sets and the good thing about it is that, given a structure with certain properties (being transitive not being one of them), you can work with another structure that is isomorphic (so elementarily equivalent) but transitive. So could someone please explain to me how the starting structure need not be transitive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what it means for $N$ to be transitive.

By definition $N$ is a transitive set if, whenever $x\in y\in N$ it holds that $x\in N$.

This is *different from* "$\in$ is transitive on $N$", which is what your question assumes -- and *that* won't be true unless in the particular case that $r$ happened to be a transitive relation to begin with.

For example, $\bigl\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}\bigr\}$ is a transitive set, even though $\in$ is not transitive on it.

Comment: Of course, thank you very much.